# Movie where aliens give boy back to his mother at the end

Tags: story-identification, movie

When I was about six, I remember seeing the last minutes of a strange movie. It involved some aliens giving a young boy (aged less than 10 or so) back to his mother due to his love for her.

I can't remember anything else, and I was randomly reminded of this today. Any help?

Comment: Was his mother white?

Comment: And when were you six?

Comment: and what did the aliens look like?

Comment: Was it Close Encounters of the Third Kind, perhaps?

Comment: I'm amazed that anyone could get this from the details given !

Comment: I was about to add the lonely house, but I might had just missed the houses around.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sounds a lot like the final scene[Artificial Intelligence: AI](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0212720/?ref_=nv_sr_1)... the aliens (and the kid) are actually robots.

If that rings some bells, the setting of that last scene is almost completely frozen (probably it was showing Earth in a -distant- future Ice Age).

[image]

The "kid" (a near-future robot) and an "alien" (a far-future robot, sentient).

[image]

The mother and the "kid" (not from the scene you described, but an earlier one).

And, finally, [youtube has the scene you were talking about](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xRhCz0ELrKs)

Comment: YES Thank you! This is the movie!

Comment: Wow. I wouldn't have even guessed that this was it. You have my +1

Comment: You have a vote. Good answer